# Capture Samsung Smart TV network requests (https)

Tags: ssl, https, tizen, network-traffic

I have a Samsung Smart TV running **[Tizen TV OS](https://docs.tizen.org/platform/what-is-tizen/profiles/tv/)**. Is there any way to capture API's from native tv apps? I know you could technically capture network traffic using a **Raspberry Pi** or **Wireshark**, but these two only capture http requests, being unable to decode **https** traffic. Is there any way to install a certificate of sorts in order to also capture https traffic? Thanks in advance.

I wanted to use a proxy server in order to redirect traffic, but sadly **Tizen TV OS** does **NOT** support proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this site firstly.

https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/

If you want to decrypt https packets captured through wireshark, you need a pre-master shared key.

However, since consumer TVs cannot use shell commands, it seems impossible to decrypt https packets.

In addition, a pre-master shared key is also required to decrypt https packets that communicate internally with the native app. If you have this key, you can try the above method.

And regarding proxy server settings, as far as I know, some Tizen TV such as B2B products support proxy server settings.